# Realm list property not saving data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm, realm-list

I have two models, lets call them Schools, and Teachers. Models are as under

```
@objcMembers public class Schools : Object {


dynamic var   Id : String = ""
dynamic var   UserId : Int64 = 0
dynamic var   Name : String? = ""
dynamic var   listTeachers : List<Teachers>? =  nil
dynamic var   teachersList : [Teachers]? =  []
   }



@objcMembers public class Teachers : Object {


dynamic var   Id : String = ""
dynamic var   UserId : Int64 = 0
dynamic var   Name : String? = ""


   }
```

now before saving data I m putting Teachers objects (list) in School object then I save that School object in realm write closure.

after that I just get the School realm object and when I get the Teachers list, it always gets Nil. What is the case?

Am i missing something or missing something to understand the real LIST property??

please help

**Update: This is how I am getting  object**

```
let mSavedItems = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(Schools.self)

if let teachers = mSavedItems[0].teachersList{// here teacher list is nil
  }
```

Comment: can you provide how are you accessing the object and returns nil ?

Comment: @Tobi question is updated. Please check

Comment: in mDbhelper are you creating a realm instance and use it within realmObj ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Schools` declaration is flawed. You shouldn't declare a `List` as dynamic or mutable, nor should you make it `Optional`. As the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#many-to-many) clearly state, `let listTeachers = List<Teachers>()` is the correct way to declare a many-to-many relationship.

Storing a property of type `Array` is also not supported by `Realm`, so you should delete the `teachersList : [Teachers]?` property.

```
@objcMembers public class Schools : Object {
    dynamic var   Id : String = ""
    dynamic var   UserId : Int64 = 0
    dynamic var   Name : String? = ""
    let listTeachers = List<Teachers>()
}
```

Comment: I am new to iOS , and swift etc. but I read somewhere that we cant manipulate let value, since it will be constant

Comment: @Androidteem yes, `let` means declaring the property immutable, but since `List` is a `class` and hence a reference type, you can still modify its properties (elements in this specific case), you just cannot change the reference of the list, which would rarely make sense doing anyways. In almost all cases you should declare `List` as immutable for this reason. If you're new to Swift, it would make even more sense to read through the Realm docs along with the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Comment: @Androidteem  i don't know how i missed this, this is the correct answer for your case, the List

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the answer. But then can you show me the way of storing item in list and then getting those Items from the list. Please share this code thanks

Comment: oh dear I got that. so we can easily set value in it and it will work